# Mudanças no código JSP para só HTML

Tags: html, jsp

Como posso incluir um formulário na minha página de JSP com Bootstrap 4. Já teitei criar um form que segue a baixo em volta do meu formulário mas não deu certo.
Ou melhor, como posso usar somente HTML5 sem tags JSP.

```
  <div class="form-group">

  </div>
</form>
```

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/save"
                modelAttribute="employee">
        Nome: <form:input path="name" />
                <br />
        Selecione o Genero: <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="Masculino" />Masculino&nbsp;
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="Feminino" />Feminino&nbsp;<br />
        Departemento: 
        <form:select path="department">
                    <form:option value="Support">Support</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Testing">Testing</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Development">Development</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</form:option>
                </form:select>
                <br />
        Data de Aniversário: <form:input path="dob" type="date" />
                <br />
                <form:hidden path="id" />
                <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
            </form:form>
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">Featured</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural
                        lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar o bootstrap na sua página jsp você deve importa-lo através da tag link. No inicio do seu JSP coloque:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Sim, você pode utilizar apenas tags HTML. Na realidade, o JSP te permite utilizar Expression Language e da JSTL (com as devidas importações) mas você pode utilizar apenas as tags html comuns.

Comment: Consegui arrumar @MatheusEdnei. A minha dúvida era como criar um formulário na minha página. Como eu tinha informado eu já estou usando o Bootstrap no meu projeto.